# Android Option Menu on Button click

Tags: android, optionmenu

I am trying to show the `Option menu` on button click.How can I do this can anyone tell me.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use [openOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29) to programmatically open the options menu.

If you have a `Button`, you can do:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openOptionsMenu();
    }
});
```

or else set `android:onClick="myOnClickMethod"` on your `Button` in xml and then have:

```
public myOnClickMethod(View v) {
    openOptionsMenu();
}
```

in your activity.

Comment: Warning -- this is completely insufficient in terms of cross-version and <Application /> configuration requirements. It is not this simple once you start considering Honeycomb, ActionBars, ICS, 4.3 bugs, etc.

Comment: @CoryTrese please tell some senarios where this can fail. If possible, giving solution to those problems will be remarkably thankful.

Comment: My project is completely on single activity with all fragments supporting version 2.3 onwards, not using android provided action bar, made my own layout header and using it as a action bar.

Comment: what happens with the activity when openOptionsMenu() is called? does it stop? does it pause? thx

Comment: I can say this much: openOptionsMenu() is failing on a Samsung Tab S 10.5 LTE running 5.0.2. It works on my other devices.

Comment: @RahulRastogi Like you said above i am using layout header as action bar. How to show the overflow menu on button click. Please look into this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297034/show-overflow-menu-on-image-button-click#33297127  and help me out. Thanks