# Menu button´s activity programming

Tags: android

I want to do a button that when I click it does the same what the menu button of the telephone would do.

I know for example that if I use `onBackPressed();` it does the same that the <kbd>back</kbd> button of the telephone would do.

Anybody knows how to do that for the menu button?

Thank you

Comment: openOptionsMenu(); sorry

Answer (score 0):

I found a link suggesting that you do this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event ) {
 if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){
  //WHATEVER YOU'D LIKE TO DO
 }
 return super.onKeyDown(keycode,event);  
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

[Source of the code](http://progrnotes.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-menu-button-click-event.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open the app's option menu, as the Menu button does, take a look here

[Android Option Menu on Button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533757/android-option-menu-on-button-click)