# openOptionsMenu not work with full-screen

Tags: android

I have an activity with full-screen mode

```
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

and I used button to open the option menu

```
dmenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                openOptionsMenu();

            }
        });
```

but when I click the button no thing happens

when I delete the full-screen theme all things work will so I can Open the menu from my button and from tablet soft menu button

how can I open the menu from my button and with full-screen mode

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am stuck with issue and couldn't find anything closer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question is already answered here
[Android Option Menu on Button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533757/android-option-menu-on-button-click)

Comment: no I want to open it with full-screen mode and the code in that answer not work with my state

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by putting the targetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml to a version prior to 11 like this :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
```

By doing this, it works and the call to openOptionsMenu() does work

Comment: In my application, using the fullscreen theme, onCreateOptionsMenu was never called. This fix works for me too..but where is this documented??