# openOptionsMenu method does not work in full-screen video when clicked on chrome cast button

Tags: android, menuitem, chromecast, android-menu, android-fullscreen

I know that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376179/openoptionsmenu-not-work-with-full-screen) question is asked before 
but I'm having bit different problem with the solution given in that particular question.
They asked to put

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>`

But what if my other dependencies or libraries require atleast `minSdkVersion="11"` or `minSdkVersion="12"` or `minSdkVersion="13"`.
    Please can anyone tell a solid solution to handle **onClick event** upon **chromecast** button within a fullscreen activity which is playing a video?

Thanks in advance for your worth words that might become a solution for me.