# Real time menu on actionbar in android

Tags: android, arraylist, menu

I want to make a list in like this with an icon on `actionbar`.

[image]

If ı clicked on icon, list must appear.

This list is realtime , and I want to fetch it's items from an arraylist (arraylist items fetching from a class). What are the steps to follow?

Comment: This menu is a customized one . Try using `PopUpWindow`.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883936/custom-menu-on-button-click-as-drop-down

Comment: it is not duplicated, my menu's items are fetching from an real time arraylist.