# Show overflow menu on Image button click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to show the Overflow menu on `ImageButton` click.

menu/menu_scrollable_tab.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context="com.example.scrollingtab.activity.ScrollableTabsActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" 
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" 
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/info" />

      <item android:id="@+id/action_settings1" 
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" 
        app:showAsAction="never" />

        <item android:id="@+id/action_settings2" 
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" 
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

I have disabled the default Action bar and created Action bar using layout. I am not using default action bar or toolbar since i need to customize the action bar more.

layout/actionbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >
 <LinearLayout      
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="@color/actionbar_bg"
     android:weightSum="2">

     <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ib_navigation"
         android:background="@drawable/nv_drawer_24x24"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight=".3"
         android:layout_height="50dp"/>

     <View 
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:layout_weight="1.1"/>

     <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ib_navigation1"
         android:background="@drawable/info"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight=".3"
         android:layout_height="50dp"/>

     <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ib_navigation2"
         android:background="@drawable/ic_drawer"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight=".3"
         android:layout_height="50dp"/>     
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As per the client requirement I have designed the action bar using layout and the look and feel are good.

The default `OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method is not populating the overflow menu. Now i want to populate the overflow menu on clicking the `ImageButton` with `id= ib_navigation2`. I don't have any idea to implement this.

Can any one help me on doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the method for creating you own menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

The buttonclick can call `openOptionsMenu();`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openOptionsMenu();
    }
});
```

Or else

```
public myOnClickMethod(View v) {
    openOptionsMenu();
}
```

See here for more information about menus
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Hope this will work for you

Comment: I have added the code for button onclick inside the onCreate method. This is working but the menu is shown at the bottom of the mobile screen. Is it possible to show the overflow menu just below the button i am clicking.

Comment: Hi Any idea how to make it below the button i am going to click.